# Pre-Symplectic Mapping

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-group

I have been studying symplectic integrators and their pre-symplectic extensions for dissipative systems. According to [França, Jordan, and Vidal - On dissipative symplectic integration with applications to gradient-based optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.06840), we can define $\Omega$ for pre-symplectic manifolds as:

$$\boldsymbol \Omega=\left(\begin{array}{c|cc}0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & 0 & -I \\ 0 & +I & 0\end{array}\right).$$

I was wondering if there is a definition of pre-symplectic matrices, like the one given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix) for the symplectic ones. Should these matrices preserve the property $\mathbf M^T\boldsymbol \Omega \mathbf M$ or this property has to be preserved only for their lower-right symplectic block? For example does the following matrix preserve pre-symplecticity?

$$ \mathbf M = \left(\begin{array}{c|cc}1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline \mathbf a_{n \times 1} & I & \mathbf B_n \\ 0 & 0 & I\end{array}\right) $$